# Como comprobar/validar en un input si un usuario existe en Active Directory?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Tengo un formulario, donde cargo los usuarios de AD a MySQL, para que puedan acceder a la web de la empresa y los que no están esa tabla, los rechaza. Mi consulta es: Desde ese input donde pongo el usuario de AD.. como puedo hacer una validación de si existe en AD o no?

en LDAP tengo esto:

```
 require_once("config.php"); 

  function mailboxpowerloginrd($user,$pass){ 
  $ldaprdn = trim($user).'@'.DOMINIO;  
  $ldappass = trim($pass);  
  $ds = DOMINIO;  
  $dn = DN;   
  $puertoldap = 389;  
  $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ds,$puertoldap); 
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);  
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);  
    $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);  
    if ($ldapbind){ 
      $filter="(|(SAMAccountName=".trim($user)."))"; 
      $fields = array("SAMAccountName");  
      $sr = @ldap_search($ldapconn, $dn, $filter, $fields);  
      $info = @ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $sr);  
      $array = $info[0]["samaccountname"][0]; 
    }else{  
          $array=0; 
    }  
  ldap_close($ldapconn);  
  return $array; 
 }
```

Y este es parte del formulario donde cargo los datos:

```
        <form  method="POST" action="../../Usuarios_Lectora/carga_userLectora.php">
           <table style="auto">
             <tr>
               <td class="td">
                 <input class="input_user" type='text' maxlength="15" name="usuario" value="" 
                 placeholder="USUARIO" required autocomplete='off' />
              </td>
            </tr>
```

No se mucho de JS o Jquery.. Si me pudieran guiar, agradeceré!